# Purpose of while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

This is the assignment.

Can somebody please explain why the below code won't run properly without While loop?
I thought it will be possible to iterate through list just using For loop.

8-9. Messages: Make a list containing a series of short text messages. Pass the
list to a function called show_messages(), which prints each text message.

8-10. Sending Messages: Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9.
Write a function called send_messages() that prints each text message and
moves each message to a new list called sent_messages as it’s printed. After
calling the function, print both of your lists to make sure the messages were
moved correctly.

`

```
 def show_messages(messages):
    for message in messages:
        print(message)


def send_messages(messages,sent_messages):
for message in messages:

    current_message = messages.pop()
    print(current_message)
    sent_messages.append(current_message)
```

## If we insert While loop under For loop code runs fine.

`messages=['Kralju!','Gofe!','Klošaru!']`
`sent_messages=[]`

`send_messages(messages,sent_messages)`

```
print(messages)
print(sent_messages)[Output][1]
```

The correct output would be 'sent_messages' with three messages while 'messages' would be empty.

So basically when you don't use While loop it pops all but the first message in 'messages'.
Not quite sure of the logic here.

Comment: Can you show a codeblock that works and the one that doesn't work, because the code you showed is incorrect and won't run anyways. So can you provide the code that worked for you with the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of this line:

```
current_message = messages.pop()
```

You can't remove items from the iterable you're iterating over in a for loop, as it will be expecting the list to be a certain length. I don't see the code you've run as a while loop but with a `while` loop you're not iterating over the `messages` list while you remove items from it.

I know the question says to start with your first function, but I'm sure it's fine if you change it from a `for` loop to a `while` loop:

```
def send_messages(messages, sent_messages):
    while messages:
        # .pop(0) so the messages are printed in the same order
        # as your first function
        current_message = messages.pop(0)
        print(current_message)

        sent_messages.append(current_message)
```

Comment: Awesome! I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you out